# StackOverflow Reputation Stopped Incrementing

Tags: support, reputation

A few days back I had 997 on StackOverflow, that same day it dropped to something 978 without any negative feedback.  It stayed at that level the rest of the day although I was getting +1's.

Then that evening it suddenly jumped to 1084.  And not it's stuck again at 1084.

What can be going on here?

Comment: Have you looked at your reputation breakdown? It certainly looks as though you've got all of it for every upvote. What makes you think that you're still getting upvotes?

Comment: You gained 100 points for the Association Bonus and most likely lost points when rep gained for a now-deleted post was removed again. See the linked post on how to read your reputation history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You received an associated bonus of 100 rep.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1971013/meaning-matters?tab=reputation

As for the other minor changes, I cannot see why.

Comment: Thanks!  Ah now I see it, I was wrongly under the impression that an upvote of a comment also earned points.

Comment: oh good, I couldn't answer that part :)

Comment: Again, thanks!  It helped that just someone else was having a look.

Comment: I have asked sooooooo many questions, always happy to help if and when I actually can :)

Comment: @YvetteColomb hello, i know this is an old question but, i got my  associated bonus of 100 rep yesterday. But today even i got 2 upvotes to my accepted answer i did get nothing. My reputation history shows yesterday as most recent. What do you think?